# Unable to create vsix extension for Universal Windows app

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have a Windows Phone 8 app which I am porting to Windows-10. The app used .**vsix** extensions for Windows Phone 8, hence I am trying to create a similar .**vsix** extension for Universal Windows app as well.
 
My SDKManifest.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" 
> encoding="utf-8" ?> <FileList  Identity = "XXX.UWP"  Version =
> "1.0"  DisplayName = "XXX Universal Windows SDK" 
> TargetPlatform="UAP"  MinVSVersion = "14.0"  SDKType="External" 
> SupportedArchitectures = "x64;ARM"  SupportsMultipleVersions = "Error"
> TargetPlatformMinVersion="10.0.10069.0" 
> TargetPlatformVersion="10.0.10069.0">  <File 
> Reference="XXX.winmd" 
> Implementation="XXX.dll"/> </FileList>
```

My VSIX Manifest file is

```
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011">
 <Metadata>
    <Identity
 Id="XXX.UWP"
 Version="1.0"
 Language="en-US"
 Publisher="XXX Inc" />
    <DisplayName>XXX SDK for Universal Windows</DisplayName>
    <Description>XXX SDK</Description>
    <License>license.txt</License>
  </Metadata>
  <Installation AllUsers="true" Scope="Global">
<InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.ExtensionSDK"
TargetPlatformIdentifier="Windows Kits"
TargetPlatformVersion="10"
SdkName="XXXSDK.UWP"
SdkVersion="1.0" />
  </Installation>
  <Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.ExtensionSDK" Path="SDKManifest.xml" />
  </Assets>
</PackageManifest>
```

I have all these xml files along with required dll's in a folder say "***myVsix***". I then zip this folder to creater "***myVsix.zip***"

Then I rename this to "***myVsix.vsix***" to create a **.vsix** file.

When I try to install this by double clicking on the file, I get the following error:

**This VSIX package is invalid because it does not contain the file extension.vsixmanifest at the root. The VSIX file may be corrupted.**

This is the error log:

```
3/3/2016 5:46:30 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
3/3/2016 5:46:30 PM - -------------------------------------------
3/3/2016 5:46:30 PM - Initializing Install...
3/3/2016 5:46:30 PM - Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.MissingPackagePartException: This VSIX package is invalid because it does not contain the file extension.vsixmanifest at the root. The VSIX file may be corrupted.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallableExtensionImpl.ReadVSIXManifestFromPackage(Stream vsixStream, CultureInfo preferredCulture)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallableExtensionImpl..ctor(String path, CultureInfo preferredCulture)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Visual Studio can't find or read the `.vsixmanifest` file. It must be misnamed or something else is wrong with it.

Instead of creating the VSIX file by hand, you should create it using the *VSIX Project* Visual Studio template:

[image: VSIX Project template]

If you can't find it in your Visual Studio copy, you should modify your installation and include the *Visual Studio Extensibility Tools*:

[image: Visual Studio Extensibility Tools]

This will automatically create a correct basic structure of the VSIX and even an editor in Visual Studio for editing the manifest which should make it much easier and more convenient to create a valid VSIX.

[image: VSIX manifest editor]

Comment: Hi @DamirArh, Thanks a lot for your response. I am able to create & use the .vsix extension if I build it with VS GUI(Graphical User Interface).
I am actually more interested in created this extension manually. Our build system is automated & as such we cannot use VS GUI to create these extensions. 
Our build system just copies all necessary resources required to create the extension to a folder, zips it & then renames it to .vsix. I tried the same process, unfortunately it is not working in Windows-10 with VS-2015.

Comment: I guess you could try comparing both vsix files and seeing where the difference is that causes the manually created one not to work. On the other hand, you probably should be able to "compile" the project created in VS on the build server as well. With all the bits installed on the build server you should be able to build the project file with MSBuild, with any build system you might be using.